# Cómo puedo obtener la fecha para una publicación PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy creando un App donde hay contactos y se pueden enviar mensajes, el esquema de base de datos es el siguiente: solo hay 2 tablas;

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` (
  id int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  usuario varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  nombre varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  contrasenya varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mensajes` (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  remitente varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  destinatario varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  mensaje varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  dataa datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Al archivo `mensajes.php` quiero que cuando un usuario envié un mensaje el campo de 'dataa' se rellene con la fecha actual, pero en lugar de eso , aparece esto: `dataa: 0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Formulario **mensajes.php**

```
<form action='enviarmensaje.php' method='post'>
    <div class='field'>
           <input class='input' placeholder='Para: (Usuario ejemplo: PepeSharingan72)' name='destinatario' type='text'>
    </div>
        <div class='field'>                         
                <textarea name='mensaje' class='textarea' 
                </textarea>                     
        <input type='hidden' name='remitente' value='".$_SESSION['usuario']."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='data' value='".$data."'>
        </div>
        <div class='field'>
        <center>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Enviar' class='button is-info'></input>
        </center>
        </div>
</form>
```

Archivo PHP SQL Enviar mensaje :

```
<?php 
include('connection.php');
session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
        $remitente = $_POST['remitente'];
        $destinatario = $_POST['destinatario'];
        $data = $_POST['data'];
            $sqlenviarmensaje = "INSERT INTO mensajes(id,remitente,destinatario,mensaje,dataa) VALUES ('dummy','".$remitente."','".$destinatario."','".$mensaje."','".$data."');";
            if(!$connect = $conn->query($sqlenviarmensaje)){
                header("location: mensajes.php?envmes=0");
            }else{
                header("location: mensajes.php?envmes=1");
            }
    }
?>
```

Mi resolución seria que al enviar un mensaje, al campo 'dataa' en lugar de aparecer:   `0000-00-00 00:00:00`, aparezca la fecha y data actual.

Comment: Prueba con `NOW()` de SQL

Comment: Acabo de borrar la tabla mensajes, sustituyendola por otra con tu versión del campo dataa, y al campo dataa me sigue apareciendo 0000-00-00 00:00:00 al hacer una publicacion..

Comment: Así debería funcionarte, sin tener que pasar por código PHP: **`ALTER TABLE 
mensajes 
MODIFY COLUMN dataa DATETIME  
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`**  he quitado el `NOT NULL`, porque al tener datos nulos fallará. Hice una prueba en rextester y funciona.

Comment: Pues a mi me sigue apareciendo lo mismo, puede ser por el insert? Como deberia hacer el insert? Mi insert esta arriba, esta bien=?

Comment: este es el formulario: 

`<form action='enviarmensaje.php' method='post'>

Comment: Y esto es la sql del insert,

`
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
  $remitente = $_POST['remitente'];
  $destinatario = $_POST['destinatario'];
  $data = $_POST['data'];
   $sqlenviarmensaje = "INSERT INTO mensajes(id,remitente,destinatario,mensaje,dataa) VALUES ('dummy','".$remitente."','".$destinatario."','".$mensaje."','".$data."');";
   if(!$connect = $conn->query($sqlenviarmensaje)){
    header("location: mensajes.php?envmes=0");
   }else{
    header("location: mensajes.php?envmes=1");
   }
 }
`

Comment: En el INSERT no incluyas la columna dataa, no tiene sentido si quieres que en ella se registre la fecha y hora actual del sistema. Si la tabla está definida como se ha indicado en la respuesta esa columna tomará su valor por defecto. Ahora que veo tu INSERT, es recomendable usar consultas preparadas para dar seguridad a tu código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con este codigo:

solo tienes que igualar la variable
ejemplo

```
$data = date("Y-m-d");
```

o si lo quieres con hora tambien puedes hacerlo asi

```
$data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

y automaticamente en el campo date de la base de datos te guardara la hora

NOTA: debes tener configurado tu php para que te guarde tu hora local

Comment: Eso de tener configurado el php para que te guarde la hora loca, me podrias hacer una pequeña demostracion de como se haria eso? gracias!!

Comment: genial que te haya servido!! es sencillo solo modifica tu php.ini busca la linea "date.timezone" yo estoy en bogota mi codigo quedaria asi "date.timezone = "America/Bogota" para buscar tu ubicacion y saber como colocar esa linea te dejo este link http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php

Answer (score 1):

Una solución es que solo modifiques la estructura de tu tabla mensajes el valor DEFAULT de dataa cambiar `NULL` por `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` y cada que hagas una inserción pondrá la fecha actual.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mensajes(
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  remitente varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  destinatario varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  mensaje varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  dataa datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en el `CREATE TABLE`, has indicado `DEFAULT NULL`, por lo que cada registro creado tendrá: `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

### Solución 1: desde el CREATE TABLE

La pongo aquí para una próxima vez. Si ya tu tabla tiene datos esta solución no te sirve (a no ser que puedas y quieres borrarla y crearla de nuevo).

Si quieres conservar la actual tabla y sus datos ver solución 2 más abajo.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mensajes(
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  remitente varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  destinatario varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  mensaje varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  dataa datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

### Solución 2: usando `ALTER TABLE`

Modifica tu actual tabla para que haga lo que deseas en lo adelante, respetando los datos existentes.

```
ALTER TABLE 
mensajes 
MODIFY COLUMN dataa DATETIME NOT NULL 
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

***Nota sobre la solución 2:***

No estoy seguro de lo que ocurrirá si tienes registros con `0000-00-00 00:00:00` e indicas `NOT NULL` al mismo tiempo.

Si da error, tendrías dos opciones:

**a.** Introducir fechas diferentes a `0000-00-00 00:00:00` en los registros que ya existen y ejecutar luego el `ALTER TABLE...`

**b.** Quitar el `NOT NULL` es esta línea: `MODIFY COLUMN dataa DATETIME` <s>`NOT NULL`</s>